# Append react app directly to body in the right way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to append my react app component directly to body as first child.
My solution is something like this (but its seem to me like **overkill**):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

const $container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.insertBefore($container, document.body.firstChild)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, $container);
```

**What its the react way to do this action?**

**Thank You!**

Comment: Looks fine to me, that's how I render my React components into my page. Not sure if there's another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to insert your `<App />` component as the first element in the document body, you could remove the two lines that set up the `$container` variable and append it, and in your last line, use `document.body` as your second argument, like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Based on your code snippet, it looks like you also need a wrapper `div`, in which case you could implement that within `./components/App.js`

Edit: I should also mention that appending directly to the body is discouraged by the creators of react-dom. You will get a console warning if you do this.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, your body can have the first child for reactjs to append.

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div>.....</div>
</body>
```

and you can write the *index.js* as usual.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```